# Сложение числе в объекте с отображением в инпуте

Tags: javascript

При сложении чисел 1 и 2 с отображение в инпуте функция plus(), которая должна отобразить сумму 3, почему-то не работает.

```js
var num1, num2, result;
var calc = {
  numbers: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
  first: function(){
    var that = this;
    document.addEventListener('keypress', function(){
      if(event.keyCode == 49) {
        document.getElementById('field').value = that.numbers[1];
        num1 = that.numbers[1];
      }
      else if(event.keyCode == 50) {
        document.getElementById('field').value = that.numbers[2];
        num2 = that.numbers[2];
      }
    function plus(){
      result = num1 + num2;
      document.getElementById('field').value = result;
    }
    plus();
    })

  }
}
calc.first();
console.log(num1);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="field" disabled>
```

Comment: У вас получается, что значения в num1 и num2 записываются только тогда, когда вы нажали клавиши с кодами 49 и 50, до этого они остаются undefined.